# I want to install a .deb package with dpkg -i on Debian but I don't know what changes it's going to make on my system

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg

I'd like to use a piece of software that's only available through a .deb package.
I don't usually like these methods because I'm afraid they can mess up my Debian system into some kind of [Frankendebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian), so I'd like to know if there's some way I could look into the installation process of *dpkg -i*  in order to see what changes it's going to make on my system.
Would something such as *dpkg --dry-run -i*  work for this?

Is it completely safe to install software through dpkg?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe see https://linux-tips.com/t/how-to-extract-deb-package/169

Answer (score 2):

You can extract package (as bodo suggested in comments) or dive into it using mc. Then you can see which files will be installed (`CONTENTS`) and what scripts will run (`DEBIAN/preinst`, `DEBIAN/postinst`).

Off course, it's not safe to install untrusted packages, because packages are always installed as superuser and `preinst` script can do anything, even `rm -rf /`

Comment: Thanks. 
I've been reading the [Debian Administrator's Handbook section on dpkg](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.manipulating-packages-with-dpkg.en.html) and I'll try the --listfiles (-L) and --info (-I) options to check what files it's going to install and where. It's a trusted package (it's a well-known cypto wallet), but I'd rather keep things clean and avoid installing software as root, so I'll use either the .AppImage or the .zip file, which can be unpacked and run out-of-the-box, without modifying my system.

Comment: AFAIK, --listfiles works only with installed packages

Comment: If it runs from a .ZIP, then it is self-contained and the `.deb` won't be dragging other packages. In my experience, AppImage may not be well integrated with your system (which is a requirement for a wallet), IMHO they are OK only if a regular install is not possible.

Comment: @xenoid, aren't AppImage files intended to be self-contained?
As far as I know, AppImage, Flatpak and Snap packages are the preferred way over having to change the whole system.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Wiki you point to, to create a FrankenDebian you have to add "alien" repositories. Installing a package with `dpkg` will use the current declared repos and should be safe. If the .deb requires software releases that aren't in your current repos, it won't install. The whole point of pdkg/apt/.deb (from the same people you trust with your OS....) is to make installs easy and safe... It's going manual which is dangerous.

Comment: To give an example, some days ago I installed NordVPN client on my Debian using their .deb file, and during the process they changed my sources.list file to add their own repository and they made some changes in important files such as resolv.conf, which is used by different services (they made it immutable and other services couldn't overwrite it).
That's why I don't trust the changes some .deb files make.